# deadlock when passing channel as argument in pipline

Tags: go

I'm coding a practice to split number into 100 groups and calculate factorial concurrently, however my code gives me deadlock.

I think the issue could be the pipeline chain initiation. Since all the functions are taking in channels as argument, I'm not clear about why the go func in main doesn't pass the given `in` channel value to `genConcurrentGroup` function when this line `total:= <- c` happens.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    in := make (chan int)
    out := make (chan float64)

    go func() {
        in <- 1005
        out = calculateFacotorial(genConcurrentGroup(in))
    }()

    fmt.Println(<-in)
    fmt.Println(<-out)

}

//split input number into groups
//the result should be a map of [start number, number in group]
//this is not heavy task so run in one go routine
func genConcurrentGroup(c chan int) chan map[int]int{
    out := make(chan map[int]int)

    go func() {
        //100 groups
        total:= <- c  //DEADLOCK HERE! Why?
        //element number in group
        elemNumber := total / 100
        extra := total % 100
        result := make(map[int]int)
        if elemNumber>0{
            //certain 100 groups
            for i:=1 ;i<=99;i++{
                result[(i-1) * elemNumber + 1] = elemNumber
            }
            result[100] = extra + elemNumber
        }else{
            //less than 100
            for i:=1;i<=total;i++{
                result[i] = 1
            }
        }

        out <- result
        close(out)
    }()
    return out
}

//takes in all numbers to calculate multiply result
//this could be heavy so can do it 100 groups together
func calculateFacotorial(nums chan map[int]int) chan float64{
    out := make(chan float64)
    total:= <- nums //DEADLOCK HERE! Why?

    go func() {

        oneResult := make(chan float64)

        for k,v := range total{
            go func() {
                t := 1.0
                for i:=0;i<v;i++{
                    t *= float64(k) + float64(i)
                }
                oneResult <- t
            }()
        }
        result := 1.0
        for n := range oneResult{
            result *= n
        }

        close(oneResult)
    }()
    return out
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. `total:= <- c  //DEADLOCK HERE! Why?`**

You need to add a buffer to your `in` channel because there is nobody receiving when you send the value.

[image]

**2. `total := <-nums //DEADLOCK HERE! Why?`**

You need to add a `sync.WaitGroup` to wait for all goroutines to end and then you can close your channel to loop over it.

[image]

**Complete code without deadlocks:**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    in := make(chan int, 1)

    in <- 1005
    out := calculateFacotorial(genConcurrentGroup(in))

    fmt.Println(<-out)

}

//split input number into groups
//the result should be a map of [start number, number in group]
//this is not heavy task so run in one go routine
func genConcurrentGroup(c chan int) chan map[int]int {
    out := make(chan map[int]int)

    go func() {
        //100 groups
        total := <-c //DEADLOCK HERE! Why?
        //element number in group
        elemNumber := total / 100
        extra := total % 100
        result := make(map[int]int)
        if elemNumber > 0 {
            //certain 100 groups
            for i := 1; i <= 99; i++ {
                result[(i-1)*elemNumber+1] = elemNumber
            }
            result[100] = extra + elemNumber
        } else {
            //less than 100
            for i := 1; i <= total; i++ {
                result[i] = 1
            }
        }

        out <- result
        close(out)
    }()
    return out
}

//takes in all numbers to calculate multiply result
//this could be heavy so can do it 100 groups together
func calculateFacotorial(nums chan map[int]int) chan float64 {
    out := make(chan float64)
    total := <-nums //DEADLOCK HERE! Why?

    go func() {
        oneResult := make(chan float64, len(total))

        var wg sync.WaitGroup
        wg.Add(len(total))

        for k, v := range total {
            go func() {
                t := 1.0
                for i := 0; i < v; i++ {
                    t *= float64(k) + float64(i)
                }
                oneResult <- t
                wg.Done()
            }()
        }

        wg.Wait()

        close(oneResult)

        result := 1.0
        for n := range oneResult {
            result *= n
        }

        out <- result

    }()
    return out
}
```

Comment: Thanks, sort of solved the issue in the first function, but I still have problem. plz look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54887502/deadlock-in-range-over-channel-in-pipeline-with-multiple-waitgroups